# AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model '%s' that has not been installed" % settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL

Tags: python, django

Here is my settings.

```
    ########## APP CONFIGURATION
DJANGO_APPS = (
    # Default Django apps:
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',

    # Useful template tags:
    # 'django.contrib.humanize',

    # Admin panel and documentation:
    'django.contrib.admin',
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
)

THIRD_PARTY_APPS = (
    'south',
    'colorful',
    #'grappelli',
    'django_extensions',
    #'rest_framework',
    #'sorl.thumbnail',
    'guardian',
    'sslserver',
    'djangosecure',
    'django_nose',
)

# Apps specific for this project go here.
LOCAL_APPS = (
    'main',
    'executor',
    'workshop',
    'management',
)
```

And here is my loaded python apps:

```
    Django < 1.7
South === 1.0
django-colorful
django-extensions == 1.5.2
django-mptt == 0.7.4
loremipsum < 1.0.4
django_debug_toolbar
werkzeug == 0.11.4
Pillow == 3.1.1
MySQL-python
xlwt
xlrd
django-guardian == 1.3.2
lxml
fabric
django-fab-deploy
django-secure === 1.0.1
django-sslserver === 0.15
python-ldap === 2.4.19
django_auth_ldap
html2text
htmlentities
openpyxl
raven
colorful
ipython == 4.1.1
django-nose
newrelic
```

I have done none code changes and now I can't create or update instances. I will get this error message in server:

```
    File "/srv/www/lohja/targetor/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/__init__.py", line 129, in get_user_model
[targetor_upgrade@targetorpro.fi] out:
raise ImproperlyConfigured("AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model '%s' that has not been installed" % settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
[targetor_upgrade@targetorpro.fi] out:
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'executor.ExecutorUser' that has not been installed
[targetor_upgrade@targetorpro.fi] out:
Fatal error: run() received nonzero return code 1 while executing!
Requested: /srv/www/lohja/targetor/env/bin/python /srv/www/lohja/targetor/manage.py migrate --fake --no-initial-data guardian --settings=settings.local_setti$
Executed: /bin/bash -l -c "cd /srv/www/lohja/targetor/env/bin/ && . /srv/www/lohja/targetor/env/bin/activate && /srv/www/lohja/targetor/env/bin/python /srv/w$
Aborting.
```

I guess there are some changes in python apps which will do this error. But I can't find which version of certain apps I have to use. I had have already this kind of problem but managed to solve those. Now, I can't find the reason... Does anyone else fix this issue?

Comment: `executor.ExecutorUser` is not found

Comment: Where is the *actual* INSTALLED_APPS setting? Does it combine all of DJANGO_APPS, THIRD_PARTY_APPS and LOCAL_APPS?

Comment: # See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#installed-apps

INSTALLED_APPS = DJANGO_APPS + THIRD_PARTY_APPS + LOCAL_APPS
########## END APP CONFIGURATION

Comment: Actually "'executor.ExecutorUser' that has not been installed". I have done no changes to code and I managed to update instances 23. april 2016. Now, I can't! So what is changed? Why these apps does not work anymore as they should? Which versions I should use to fix this error?

Comment: Is it resolved or not?

Answer (score 0):

Could be due to missing django make sure all the requirement have been install. If you are using VirtualEnv make sure you activate prior to starting your server using manage.py

Comment: There is django < 1.7 in first place to loaded apps. 
Yes it is there. I don't use virtualEnv in server. Everything did work in 23. april 2016. Something has happened after that day and now I can't update any instances. What has changed? Is there some error in some apps?