# Python Django - "AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model '%s' that has not been installed" % settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL

Tags: python, django, mixins

If there is any bug in my code (code within a model that is used within a view which uses LoginRequiredMixin ) e.g. A bug like:

```
if (True:    # <-- example bug to show how bugs like this are hidden
```

Then I get the following error:

```
"AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model '%s' that has not been installed" % settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 
AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'auth.User' that has not been installed
```

This makes it really hard to debug the code. I have figured out if I remove this line from my views.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
```

Even if I remove all instances where LoginRequiredMixin is used, just by importing it, it hides the true bug and generates the above auth error.

I have read: [AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model '%s' that has not been installed" % settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37028655/auth-user-model-refers-to-model-s-that-has-not-been-installed-settings-aut?rq=1)

My research shows most of the time this is due to "django.contrib.auth'" missing from INSTALLED_APPS, which you can see I have (settings.py snippet, Django 2.2):

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth', # <-- Important for this topic!
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'myapp.apps.CommonConfig',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]
```

I tried adding this to above the mixim import but neither helped:

```
from django.contrib import auth
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

This part of the full traceback agrees with the above:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\myproject-wc-xNQPL\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 155, in get_app_config
    return self.app_configs[app_label]
KeyError: 'auth'
```

Here is the traceback if I call makemigrations (This is what I expect):

```
    C:\code\myproject\src>pipenv run python manage.py makemigrations
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\myproject-wc-xNQPL\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\myproject-wc-xNQPL\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\myproject-wc-xNQPL\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\myproject-wc-xNQPL\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\myproject-wc-xNQPL\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\myproject-wc-xNQPL\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\code\myproject\src\myapp\models.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .sql import myapp_entry_clean, myapp_entry_grouping
  File "C:\code\myproject\src\myapp\sql.py", line 68
    if (True:
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

C:\code\myproject\src>
```

Here is the traceback with runserver:

```
    C:\code\myproject\src>pipenv run python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\myproject-wc-xNQPL\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\myproject-wc-xNQPL\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\myproject-wc-xNQPL\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 77, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[0](_exception[1]).with_traceback(_exception[2])
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\myproject-wc-xNQPL\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\myproject-wc-xNQPL\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\myproject-wc-xNQPL\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\myproject-wc-xNQPL\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\myproject-wc-xNQPL\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\code\myproject\src\myapp\models.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .sql import myapp_entry_clean, myapp_entry_grouping
  File "<string>", line None
SyntaxError: invalid syntax (sql.py, line 68)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\myproject-wc-xNQPL\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 155, in get_app_config
    return self.app_configs[app_label]
KeyError: 'auth'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\myproject-wc-xNQPL\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\__init__.py", line 165, in get_user_model
    return django_apps.get_model(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, require_ready=False)
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\myproject-wc-xNQPL\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 205, in get_model
    app_config = self.get_app_config(app_label)
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\myproject-wc-xNQPL\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 162, in get_app_config
    raise LookupError(message)
LookupError: No installed app with label 'auth'.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\myproject-wc-xNQPL\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\myproject-wc-xNQPL\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\myproject-wc-xNQPL\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\myproject-wc-xNQPL\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 60, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\myproject-wc-xNQPL\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\myproject-wc-xNQPL\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 95, in handle
    self.run(**options)
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\myproject-wc-xNQPL\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 102, in run
    autoreload.run_with_reloader(self.inner_run, **options)
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\myproject-wc-xNQPL\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 579, in run_with_reloader
    start_django(reloader, main_func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\myproject-wc-xNQPL\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 564, in start_django
    reloader.run(django_main_thread)
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\myproject-wc-xNQPL\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 272, in run
    get_resolver().urlconf_module
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\myproject-wc-xNQPL\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 80, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\myproject-wc-xNQPL\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py", line 564, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\myproject-wc-xNQPL\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\code\myproject\src\linkcube\urls.py", line 20, in <module>
    path('', include('common.urls')),
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\myproject-wc-xNQPL\lib\site-packages\django\urls\conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\myproject-wc-xNQPL\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\code\myproject\src\common\urls.py", line 5, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "C:\code\myproject\src\common\views.py", line 9, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\myproject-wc-xNQPL\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\mixins.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.views import redirect_to_login
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\myproject-wc-xNQPL\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\views.py", line 10, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.forms import (
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\myproject-wc-xNQPL\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\forms.py", line 20, in <module>
    UserModel = get_user_model()
  File "C:\Users\User\.virtualenvs\myproject-wc-xNQPL\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\__init__.py", line 170, in get_user_model
    "AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model '%s' that has not been installed" % settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: AUTH_USER_MODEL refers to model 'auth.User' that has not been installed

C:\code\myproject\src>
```

How do I make it so that the auth error is not falsely raised?

Comment: What do you have in your `sql.py` file at line number 68?

Comment: The intentionally placed bug (extra bracket): "if (True:"

Comment: I think I know what your issue is, but before I comment on that, I would like to see what is in there your `sql.py` file.

Comment: sql.py was a random file I chose to place the made up bug in to demonstrate how the bugs are masked. I could have placed it in any file.

Comment: I have the same problem too! It appears by updating Django from 2.0 to 2.2 version. Has anyone understood how to solve?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the issue here is a python syntax error, but (maybe) since you are running Django framework, Django suppresses that and throws the missing model error.

Since python is interpreted language it threw an error for `SyntaxError` and since there was syntax error Django did not find auth model reference.

That's why you see both the errors there, python's `SyntaxError` and Django's `ImproperlyConfigured` error.

Django is kind enough to let you know that the Django's error is caused by the python's syntax error.

Comment: This is helpful to understand why it's happening. Maybe one can't suppress the django error, but ideally, I would like to see my error, since I know the Django framework is good, and my code is the culprit.

Comment: I understand that it's good to know the reason of the error, but it wouldn't be better if you give a way to explicit the error that Django is trying to hide?

Answer (score 2):

If you are getting that error message, I belive you are using a custom user model.
You may want to try to use **AUTH_USER_MODEL** on your relationships instead of the direct model **User** or the ****get_user_model** method**. This pretty much cleared the bug for me.
I got the solution from https://learndjango.com/tutorials/django-best-practices-referencing-user-model

> The way to use **AUTH_USER_MODEL**  is by first importing it from the settings using`from django.conf import settings` and on the field that requires the relationship, you use it as, for example `seller = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)`